# Rest api return all users (even without content) to all users

Tags: users, permissions, rest-api

I'm using the REST API to return a list of all users (using Vue) on an Intranet site. I'm using this code to allow the API to return them:

```
add_filter( 'rest_user_query', 'custom_rest_user_query' );
function custom_rest_user_query($prepared_args, $request = null)
{
    unset($prepared_args['has_published_posts']);
    return $prepared_args;
}
```

This works, but not for the subscriber role who seems to lack some permission. I want to loosen up the permissions a bit so they can view this content as well. How can I do this? I'm authenticating with the users nonce.

The problem arises when a subscribers views the profile (other than themselves) of a user who has not published anything, the console will then log:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 403
    at createError (mysite/app/themes/bintra/dist/js/main.js?ver=1507533808:18001:16)
    at settle (mysite/app/themes/bintra/dist/js/main.js?ver=1507533808:17971:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (mysite/app/themes/bintra/dist/js/main.js?ver=1507533808:17844:8)
```

The request looks like this:

```
fetchData() {
    employee = axios.get(rest_url + 'users/' + user_id, {
            headers: {
                'X-WP-Nonce': nonce
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.employee = response.data;
            this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            this.errors.push(e);
            console.log(this.errors);
        });
}
```

I pass the nonce, user_id and rest_url to js with wp_localize_script.

What can I do?

Comment: which request is send which send this 403 error ?

Comment: Updated my question with this info.

Comment: to allow subscribers to see all users, you can add the capabilities `list_users` to this role. this capabilities permits what you want without need of the modification of `has_published_posts`.

Comment: That's it! I wasn't aware of this permission, it fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!